# Validate MathText string at runtime

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, pyqt5

I am trying to build a GUI that contains a Matplotlib embedded panel. One of the widget (QLineEdit) is for the legend label and when people are enterring a value there it is directly changed in the graph (using self.widget.textChanged). All this part works great and as expected except in the following case: when people are entering latex symbols and that one is badly written I get a ValueError that I can't figure out how to catch.

A typical traceback when I enter '$$':

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 2516, in parse
result = self._expression.parseString(s)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1632, in parseString
raise exc
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1622, in parseString
loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1529, in _parseCache
value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1379, in _parseNoCache
loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 3717, in parseImpl
return self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1529, in _parseCache
value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1379, in _parseNoCache
loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 3395, in parseImpl
loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1529, in _parseCache
value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1383, in _parseNoCache
loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 3183, in parseImpl
raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected end of text (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/alien/Dropbox/Vcatpy/src/VcatPy", line 974, in make_scatplot
self.win.draw()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 133, in draw
super(FigureCanvasQTAggBase, self).draw()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 430, in draw
self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1299, in draw
renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
a.draw(renderer)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2437, in draw
mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
a.draw(renderer)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/legend.py", line 772, in draw
bbox = self._legend_box.get_window_extent(renderer)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.py", line 263, in get_window_extent
w, h, xd, yd, offsets = self.get_extent_offsets(renderer)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.py", line 385, in get_extent_offsets
for c in self.get_visible_children()]
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.py", line 385, in <listcomp>
for c in self.get_visible_children()]
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.py", line 256, in get_extent
w, h, xd, yd, offsets = self.get_extent_offsets(renderer)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.py", line 456, in get_extent_offsets
for c in self.get_visible_children()]
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.py", line 456, in <listcomp>
for c in self.get_visible_children()]
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.py", line 256, in get_extent
w, h, xd, yd, offsets = self.get_extent_offsets(renderer)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.py", line 385, in get_extent_offsets
for c in self.get_visible_children()]
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.py", line 385, in <listcomp>
for c in self.get_visible_children()]
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.py", line 256, in get_extent
w, h, xd, yd, offsets = self.get_extent_offsets(renderer)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.py", line 456, in get_extent_offsets
for c in self.get_visible_children()]
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.py", line 456, in <listcomp>
for c in self.get_visible_children()]
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.py", line 829, in get_extent
bbox, info, d = self._text._get_layout(renderer)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 317, in _get_layout
ismath=ismath)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 231, in get_text_width_height_descent
self.mathtext_parser.parse(s, self.dpi, prop)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 3303, in parse
box = self._parser.parse(s, font_output, fontsize, dpi)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 2522, in parse
six.text_type(err)]))
ValueError: 
$$
^
Expected end of text (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And thie crashes all the GUI.

The command leading to this error is:

```
self.plot.legend(handles, labels)
```

where `handles, labels` are coming from

```
handles, labels = self.plot.get_legend_handles_labels()`
```

I tried to catch the error with a simple:

```
try:
    self.plot.legend(handles, labels)
except ValueError:
    print('ok')
```

I also made sure that the labels are in the raw-string format with `r'my label'`.

But I could not make it work... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

An example, not with the legends but with the axis labels is given below:

```
####Public General Libraries
import sys

######Qt5
from PyQt5 import *
import PyQt5.QtCore as QtCore
import PyQt5.QtGui as QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

###matplotlib
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor

class Main_window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        self.initUI() 

    def initUI(self):

        ### 1 we create the grid
        self.Global = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(self.Global)
        grid= QGridLayout()
        self.Global.addLayout(grid)

        ### a- space for plot
        self.tab = QTabWidget()
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.figure.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0, right=0.95, top=0.94, left=0.15)
        self.win = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.win, self.win)
        grid.addWidget(self.win,0, 0, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.toolbar, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.plot = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.plot.legend()

        #### c- labels
        self.xlabl = QLineEdit('qwdwed')
        grid.addWidget(self.xlabl, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.xlabl.textChanged.connect(self.changexlabl)
        self.xlabl.setText('Xlabel')


        self.ylabl = QLineEdit('qwdwed')
        grid.addWidget(self.ylabl, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.ylabl.textChanged.connect(self.changeylabl)
        self.ylabl.setText('Ylabel')


        self.win.draw()
        self.show()


    def changeylabl(self):
        try:
            self.plot.set_ylabel(self.ylabl.text())
        except:
            self.plot.set_ylabel('Y-label')
        self.win.draw()

    def changexlabl(self):
        try:
            self.plot.set_xlabel(self.xlabl.text())
        except:
            self.plot.set_xlabel('X-label')

        self.win.draw()


###and start the tui
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = Main_window()
main.setFixedSize(730, 1030)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't think `$$` is a valid MathText string. So I guess the error is expected. How do you draw the frame? Best provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes I know '$$' is invalid, this is the point. The aim is to try to catch when some invalid latex string are written. The traceback gives `ValueError: 
$$` so I thought I could try to catch this and when it is detected, not to refresh the plot.

Comment: Yep, but the error occurs at drawtime so you do not have access to the call that causes the error, and you would not want to catch the draw event anyways, since then nothing gets drawn (or only half of the plot or so). The solution is surely to make sure any string set to the legend *is* actually valid. There are surely some options, but tbh I would like a [mcve] case to try those out.

Comment: I updated a minimal working example. If you try to add $$ in one of the labels you will have the same error as described in the post. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem boils down to finding out if a given string is a valid mathtext, or just valid in general. Since we shouldn't put the drawing itself inside a `try/except`, as this would still try to render the figure and in case of an error stop halfway through, the idea would be to let matplotlib evaluate the string first and only if that succeeds, draw the figure.

To this end we would set the string in question to the label and call the label's `_get_layout` function. If this succeeds, we know that drawing is save, otherwise we catch the error without drawing the canvas.

```
def changelabl(self, which="y"):
    if which=="y":
        lab = self.plot.yaxis.label
        text = self.ylabl.text()
    else:
        lab = self.plot.xaxis.label
        text = self.xlabl.text()
    try:
        lab.set_text(text)
        lab._get_layout(self.figure.canvas.renderer)
    except:
        pass
    else:
        self.win.draw_idle()
```

The complete example would look like this. (Note that I used Qt4 here, it should work as it is, replacing every `4` by `5`.)

```
import sys
######Qt5
from PyQt4 import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
###matplotlib
#import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor


class Main_window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self) 
        self.initUI() 

    def initUI(self):
        ### 1 we create the grid
        self.Global = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(self.Global)
        grid= QGridLayout()
        self.Global.addLayout(grid)

        ### a- space for plot
        self.tab = QTabWidget()
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.figure.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0, right=0.95, top=0.94, left=0.15)
        self.win = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.win, self.win)
        grid.addWidget(self.win,0, 0, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.toolbar, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.plot = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.plot.legend()

        #### c- labels
        self.xlabl = QLineEdit('qwdwed')
        grid.addWidget(self.xlabl, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.xlabl.textChanged.connect(lambda : self.changelabl("x"))
        self.xlabl.setText('Xlabel')

        self.ylabl = QLineEdit('qwdwed')
        grid.addWidget(self.ylabl, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.ylabl.textChanged.connect(lambda : self.changelabl("y"))
        self.ylabl.setText('Ylabel')

        self.win.draw()
        self.show()


    def changelabl(self, which="y"):
        if which=="y":
            lab = self.plot.yaxis.label
            text = self.ylabl.text()
        else:
            lab = self.plot.xaxis.label
            text = self.xlabl.text()
        try:
            lab.set_text(text)
            lab._get_layout(self.figure.canvas.renderer)
        except:
            pass
        else:
            self.win.draw_idle()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = Main_window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```