# Why can the try loop not catch a ParseException from Matplotlib mathtext?

Tags: matplotlib, user-interface, canvas, try-catch, wxpython

wxPython 4.2.0 x Matplotlib 3.6.0

I'm working on a GUI where the user can write a figure title in a textctrl, then this title is set on a figure and the figure is shown.

My current problem is that I don't understand why the try loop can't catch the ParseException occuring when the title is a wrong math text.

A simplified code of my issue is :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MainFrame(parent=None, title="Test")
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title=title)
        fig = plt.figure()
        fig.suptitle('$$')
        try:
            self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, 0, fig)
        except:
            self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, 0, plt.figure())
        plt.close()
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox.Add(self.canvas)
        self.SetSizer(hbox)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    raise exc.with_traceback(None)
pyparsing.exceptions.ParseException: Expected end of text, found '$'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
...
...
ValueError:
$$
^
Expected end of text, found '$'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

The try loop should catch that, am I wrong ?

For instance, I used the set_parse_math(False) method so that the error can't happen, however, I would like to understand what's wrong with this code.

Comment: I don't believe you have done anything wrong. It failed before it reached your `except` statement. It blew a gasket in the matplotlib code.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, thanks for your comment

In fact I thought it was the purpose of the try/except structure: to catch such exception.

My understanding: if an exception is raised between the try and except statements, then line after the except statement are executed.

Why is the except statement not executed here ?

Comment: And why is the exception shown instead of being handled by the try structure ?

Comment: I suspect that it's related to the fact that an exception occurred during another exception, not once but twice. Something your somewhat truncated error Traceback omitted. Somewhere in there, there exceptions occurring which aren't being caught by try..except blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on following discussion:

[Validate MathText string at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572340/validate-mathtext-string-at-runtime)

Here is my working code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
import wx

mpl.use('Agg') # important

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MainFrame(parent=None, title="Test")
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title=title)
        self.Maximize()
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.fig.add_subplot()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, 0, self.fig)
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox.Add(self.canvas)
        self.txtctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.txtctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.on_text)
        hbox.Add(self.txtctrl)
        self.SetSizer(hbox)
        plt.close()

    def verif_fig_text(self):
        self.Freeze()
        self.canvas.figure = plt.figure()
        ax = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot() # needed to insert x_label
        self.canvas.draw() # needed to get self.canvas.renderer attr
        valid_txt = True
        try:
            txt = ax.set_xlabel(self.txtctrl.GetValue()) 
            # insert x_label is the only mean to verif correct math text
            txt._get_layout(self.canvas.renderer)
            # indeed _get_layout() doesnt work with lot of stuff - found on Valid Mathtext string at runtime StackOverflow
        except:
            valid_txt = False # can't do much here, by adding anything else, the exception occurs outside the try loop
        plt.close()
        self.Thaw()
        return valid_txt
    
    def on_text(self, event):
        if self.verif_fig_text():
            self.fig.suptitle(self.txtctrl.GetValue())
        else:
            self.fig.suptitle('Wrong math text')
        self.canvas.figure = self.fig
        self.canvas.draw()
        plt.close()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

In fact, when there's a wx.EVT_TEXT, I set a new (temporary) figure to self.canvas. On this figure I add a subplot, then I set the xlabel value with the textctrl value, I use the _get_layout() method to check if the text is a correct math text, then if yes, I set this text as the title of my initial figure and I set it back as self.canvas.figure before the self.canvas.draw()